# Why does this code always generate zero when I want to generate random numbers? How can I fix the problem?

Tags: c++, class, random-seed, seed, srand

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<time.h> 
 
using namespace std;
 
class mRND
{
    public:
        void seed()
        {
            srand(time(0)); 
            _seed = rand();
        }
 
    protected:
        mRND() : _seed(), _a(), _c(), _m(2147483648)
        {
        }
        int rnd()
        {
            return (_seed = (_a * _seed + _c) % _m);
        }
 
        int _a, _c;
        unsigned int _m, _seed;
};

int main() {
    mRND r;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    cout<< r.rnd()<<endl;
    
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You never give _seed, _a or _c any values, so it just keeps using 0 and 0*0+0 = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```cpp
return (_seed = (_a * _seed + _c) % _m);
```

`_a` is 0 so the returned value is 0 and it never changes (since `_a` is always 0).

Answer (score -8):

Try setting time as "NULL" rather than zero. Zero, in this case, would likely mean midnight on January 1st, 1970. If this is the case, you would keep getting the random seed that occurs with that time.